# Unable to open config file: /etc/xen/guest4.cfg

Tags: virtualbox, virtualization, xen

I have installed XEN hypervisor on VirtualBox. I want to create virtual machine. I have followed all the steps but when finally I try to use the final step for creation VM:

```
root@ubuntu:~# sudo xm create /etc/xen/guest4.cfg -c
Error: Unable to open config file: /etc/xen/guest4.cfg
Usage: xm create <ConfigFile> [options] [vars]

Create a domain based on <ConfigFile>.
```

Kindly I need your help.

Comment: What were "all the steps you have followed"?

Answer (score 0):

**I had already created 3 virtual machine before 3 months. Now I want to create VM4. In VM4 creation it creation its creating problem. The error is Error: Unable to open config file: /etc/xen/guest4.cfg
Usage: xm create  [options] [vars]**

1)    #sudo apt-get install xen-hypervisor-amd64
  2)   #sudo sed -i 's/GRUB_DEFAULT=.*+/GRUB_DEFAULT="Xen 4.1-amd64"/'  /etc/default/grub
  3)  #sudo update-grub
  4)   #sudo sed -i 's/TOOLSTACK=.*+/TOOLSTACK="xm"/' /etc/default/xen
  5)  Reboot
    #sudo reboot

6) Verify that the installation has succeeded.
   #sudo xm list
  7) Network Configuration 
       **Xen has been successfully installed**
1)
Install LVM

## sudo apt-get update

## sudo apt-get install lvm2

2)
Create Volume Group and Logical Volume.

## sudo mkdir /mnt/vmdisk

## sudo dd if=/dev/zero of=/mnt/vmdisk/mydisk1 bs=100M count=10

## sudo losetup /dev/loop1 /mnt/vmdisk/mydisk1

## sudo pvcreate /dev/loop1

## sudo vgcreate -s 512M myvolume-group1 /dev/loop1

## sudo lvcreate -L 512M -n mylogical_volume1 myvolume-group1

## ls /dev

3)
Get netboot images

## sudo mkdir -p /var/lib/xen/images/ubuntu-netboot

## cd /var/lib/xen/images/ubuntu-netboot

## sudo wget http://mirror.anl.gov/pub/ubuntu/dists/precise/main/installer-amd64/current/images/netboot/xen/initrd.gz

## sudo wget http://mirror.anl.gov/pub/ubuntu/dists/precise/main/installer-amd64/current/images/netboot/xen/vmlinuz

4)
Set up the initial guest configuration

## vim /etc/xen/ubuntu.cfg

name = "ubuntu"
memory = 256
disk = ['phy:/dev/myvolume-group1/mylogical_volume1,xvda,w']
vif = [' ']
kernel = "/var/lib/xen/images/ubuntu-netboot/vmlinuz"
ramdisk = "/var/lib/xen/images/ubuntu-netboot/initrd.gz"
extra = "debian-installer/exit/always_halt=true -- console=hvc0"

5) (

> The Problem is in this step. its not creating the virtual machine.

)
Start the VM and connect to console (-c).

## sudo xm create -c /etc/xen/ubuntu.cfg

6)
List VMs

## sudo xm list